# How to create a frontend plugin in TYPO3

Tags: php, typo3

I'm trying to create a simple frontend plugin in TYPO3, .

I want to be able do putit into my backend template, just like I am able to put a *regular text element*, a *table* or a *bullet list*.

[image]

The plugin should have two textfields, that people should be able to fill in:

Invoice Number & Title

Then when the it is put into the page, the frontend should render it as following:

```
<a href="domain/invoices/{invoice number}.pdf"> {title} </a>
```

How can I achieve this, I tried using the Extension Builder, but I couldn't get the fields to end up in the typo3 backend.

N.B. I'm not looking for a specific solution for this problem, I'm just trying to create (more complex) frontend plugins and simplified this problem for the sake of understanding the general principle.

Comment: This would probably be too much to explain in just an SO post. you can meet me in the IRC #typo3 if you want more informations on this, same nickname ;)

Comment: @Xatenev it's already explained at SO ;> see my answer

Answer (score 2):

I described creating plugins and inserting it to the Wizard tabs in the [**other answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18464498/1066240) so probably all you must do is to follow it step by step.

Additionall fields of plugin you just need to define the FlexForm (sorry, it's too broad to describe, hope you know the approach)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a content element to display a link to an invoice, based on the invoice number entered in the content element on that page, you can use [fluidcontent](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/fluidcontent) & [flux](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux) to generate a content element of your taste. Have a look at the fluidcontent_bootstrap for examples.

If you want to creating an ext. where you can can retrieve a list of invoiced that has been added to the DB (or some other source) , then the extension_builder is a good kickstarter. If you set a front end plugin in the builder, it would shown up in the plugin list (not in the tab itself, but in the dropdown list if you would choose general plugin, first)

For the extra field: What you propably missed it the use of flexforms in your extension.