# How to create custom "New content element" in Typo3 6.2.X back-end?

Tags: typo3, customization, backend, typo3-6.2.x

I'm new to Typo3 and need guidance. Is it possible to clone and modify the existing "New Content Element", such that I could add custom input variables to add new records. My intention is to have the following fields as input layout: 
1. Title 
2. Sub-title 
3. Picture upload (optional) or URL to picture
4. Description.

so what could be the best approach to do this (I'm using v 6.2.11)? Looking forward to suggestion and working examples. Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to quickly create custom content elements in TYPO3 6.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464356/how-to-quickly-create-custom-content-elements-in-typo3-6-x)

Answer (score 0):

Here: [**How to quickly create custom content elements in TYPO3 6.x**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18464498/1066240) - you'll find full description. It's popular question/answer here on StackOverflow, so there's no reason to copy it to new answer.

Comment: I am trying that now, few confusions though. Where to put the following block of code: 

$currentTtContent = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->data;
$header = $currentTtContent['header'];
debug($currentTtContent);
debug($header);

Also, are 'hello' and 'News' case sensitive while I follow your codes there?

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [FluidTYPO3-framework](https://fluidtypo3.org). It is a very flexible way to create new content elements, but not as flexible as the approach described in biesiors answer.

To create new content elements, you would need to install the extensions `flux` and `fluidcontent`, and then create a provider extension (providing new content elements) yourself. In that extension, you create one fluid template for each new content element. It consists of

- A form to configure the content element
- A preview of the element in the backend
- A rendering definition for the frontend
- Some supporting stuff, e.g. language labels.

All this works with the fluid engine, so you have to know how to use it.

Details on how to configure the provider extension can be found on the [project home page](https://fluidtypo3.org).